Regarding Azure DevOps Test run
I have a automation test project in azure DevOps in which I have created a test plan. I am unable to access some features in this portal like in run explorer, I can not see the test result. and some time I can not create the new release. Look forward to get a solution for this.
I have checked the Azure DevOps services in https://learn.microsoft.com/ but could not get any solution for this.

It's possibly permission related. Get a project, or organisation administrator to verify you have the following:

View Test Runs:

To view test results in Run Explorer, you usually need the "View test runs" permission at the project or test plan level.


Read Permissions:

Ensure you have read permissions for the test plans, test suites, and test cases that you want to access results for.


Project-Level Permissions:

At the project level, you might need permissions like "Read," "View project-level information," or similar permissions to access test-related features.


Test Plan Permissions:

If the test plan is shared with specific users or groups, ensure that you are included in the appropriate security groups or have been explicitly granted access to the test plan.


Test Suite Permissions:

Similarly, if the test suites within the test plan have unique security settings, ensure that you have the necessary permissions to view the test suites.



